# About flash's setInterval api call

Tags: flash

```
  setInterval(func, 1000)
```

What if the `func` takes longer than `1000` ms, will the next call wait for `1000` ms or execute right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash runtime is single threaded. So whenever there is an action to perform (a function call) then it get queued to the already pending actions. So at any point of time only one function is being executed.
 In your case If you function `func` is taking more than 1000  ms to execute i.e. if `func` is in between its execution and time interval expires a new call to `func` is queued. So as soon as first `func` is finished executing then the next call will be picked if there is any. In this case it will be another `func` call. If there were other listener which were called before this then they will be called in order.

Comment: Just to be clear, while this function is taking 1000ms to execute, Flash will be doing nothing else whatsoever - no timers, no mouse events, no screen updates.

Comment: @fenomas: Agreed! Thats why it is important to architect your solution in a proper way. Don'y try to do everything in a single big function. Try to make it more event driven.

Answer (score 0):

The callback method will be invoked every 1000ms if there's nothing much else going on.

I have half a piece of code written out to elaborate a way to call an interval every 1000ms, and depending on a boolean value the interval re-invokes or deletes itself. Let me know if you want me to paste.

Edit: See answer from bhups, much better description - still let me know if you want that code I mentioned.